# Load external fonts by select menu

Tags: jquery, fonts, font-face, external

I try to make something like this... Choose font from select menu, then call jquery function and prepend css to head, load exernal font and change font-family on "#target" DIV. But it does not work...

HTML

```
<select id="sel_font">
    <option value="Roboto-Regular"></option>
    <option value="Roboto-Thin"></option>
    <option value="Roboto-ThinItalic"></option>
</select>
<div id="target">
    some text
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 $('#sel_font').change(function() {
    $("head").prepend('<style type=\"text/css\"> @font-face { font-family: \" ' + $(this).val() + '\"; src: url(\"fonts/' + $(this).val() + '.ttf\") format(\"truetype\"); } </style>');
    $("#target").css("font-family", $(this).val());
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Google webfont loader](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader):

```
//blank urls, you should use your own 
//(because of Cross-Origin policy they will not be loaded - 
//for this example it does not matter, because these fonts are embedded in a browser
var urls = {
    "Sans-serif": "http://www.corsproxy.com/github.com/Rydgel/archlinux/raw/master/.fonts/CAMBRIA.TTC",
    "Consolas": "http://www.corsproxy.com/github.com/Rydgel/archlinux/raw/master/.fonts/CAMBRIA.TTC"
};

//all fonts should be inserted in ``head`` in a one single ``style`` tag
var text = '<style type=\"text/css\">';
for (var k in urls) {
    text += '@font-face { font-family: \"' + k + '\"; src: url(\"' + urls[k] + '\") format(\"truetype\");  } '; 
}
$("head").prepend(text + '</style>');

$('#sel_font').change(function() {
    console.log('Inside a change function: '+ $('#sel_font').val())

    WebFont.load({
        custom: { 
            families: [$('#sel_font').val()]
        },
        active: function () { 
            console.log('Inside a callback: ' + $('#sel_font').val());
            $("#target").css("font-family", $('#sel_font').val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it does not work for me... Did I make some mistake ? Is this code right ? :)

Comment: I will try to create a fiddle for you in next minutes.

Comment: There are a few problems with Cross-Origin policy, but it should not be a problem for you, if your js would work from the same domain with fonts. In my Chrome browser fiddle works fine.

Comment: Thank you for helping e, but... You know, this jsfiddle loads all fonts in the same time, at begining. But I need to load just one font after the choosing from select menu.